# Force excel formula to update when non related cell value changes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to track how many issues I close per hour.

I take a start time and compare that to the current time to see how long ive been at work, then subtract an amount of time for lunch, and subtract amount of time away from my desk to get how long Ive actually been working.

Now I take how long Ive actually been working and divide that by how many issues I have closed to see how many issues I have closed per hour.

I have the below metrics:

- `A20:  2:00 PM`  (start time)
- `C20:  0:30`     (Length of Lunch)
- `E20:  0:00`     (Length of time away from desk, different project etc..)

Formula to return decimal representation of hours worked:

- `B20:  =HOUR(NOW()-A20-C20-E20)+MINUTE(NOW()-A20-C20-E20)/60`
- `F20:  25`       (issues worked, this number changes throughout the day)

Now I need to do `G20: =(F20/B20)`

When `B20` changes, `G20` is updated as you'd expect.

The problem is that since none of the cells related to the formula in `B20` have changed, that value is not updated before `G20` is calculated

**How can I force the formula in `B20` to update when the value of `F20` changes?**

VBA would be acceptable also (and probably easier) Im just not very familiar with VBA

Comment: Why do want it to?  If it's inputs haven't changed, it's value won't change either.

Comment: Because NOW() has changed

Comment: @delightedDOD Then you don't need to do anythin special.  So long as calculation is set to Automatic, B20 will update when the sheet recalculates, _because its inputs have changed_

Comment: Thats what I thought too but for whatever reason that does not happen with my example. It just kept right on using the value that was calculated when I first entered the formula in B20. The only way I could get B20 to update was to click in the formula bar and press enter

Comment: I set up a sheet as described in your OP, and it _does_ recalc for me.  Maybe there is more to your workbook than you have posted....  Are you sure you have Recalculation set to Automatic?

Comment: Thats weird, I was doing this at work. It wouldnt change for anything. I just tried it at home and your right, it works as originally expected. Ill check Recalculation is set to Automatic tomorrow, though I cant imagine how it could have gotten changed.... something must be wrong there

Comment: Really people, tell me WHY the -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your b20 formula add a dummy operation including f20 for example

```
=....+F20-F20
```

Comment: You Sir are a genius. It would boggle your mind what all ive tried to get this to work. Thank you!